# Как сервису работать с БД Room?

Tags: java, android, room

**Use case**: приложение получает текст, отправляет его на сервер и получает аудиофайлы. Эти аудиофайлы должны сохраняться на устройстве и `uri` этих файлов должны добавляться к записи в БД. Сервис с аудиопроигрывателем должен слушать изменения этого файла в бд и получать обновления списка `uri`.

**Проблема**: Изначально логика сохранения файлов была в самом приложении, в репозитории, однако такой подход имеет существенный минус - так как сервис живет дольше приложения, оно может быть вычищено из памяти, что не позволит далее обновлять запись в БД. Соот-но необходимо вынести логику сохранения записи в БД внутрь сервиса, однако тут встаёт вопрос правильного получения самого Room: передать в сервис объект Room мы не можем .

**Вопрос**: Как правильно организовать доступ к БД (Room) из сервиса.

```
appDatabase =  Room.databaseBuilder(getApplicationContext(), AppDatabase.class, "database")
                .build();
```

Код выше, вызванный из сервиса, вернёт уже существующий экземпляр БД, или новый?

Comment: Вам нужен синглтон объекта БД. Тогда он будет один везде. Правильнее всего его создавать и получать с помощью DI фреймворков. Например ToothPick или Dagger2

Comment: У меня сейчас он является синглотоном, но как его передавать в сервис? И не вызовет ли это memory leak после уничтожения приложения?

Comment: По поводу memory leak - просто экземпляр БД у меня хранится в Application классе

Comment: Передавать в сервис и не надо, надо в нём получать. Если оно уже у вас синглтон - то просто получите его там. Например как-то так: `((ApplicationClassName)getApplicationContext()).getDatabaseSinglton()`. Если приложение уничтожено - то и утекать нечему, проблем тут не возникнет.